# How to differentiate 2 NICs with the same PCI address

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, pci

I am running Fedora 22, and have a GPU that I passthrough to a KVM guest. I accomplished this by adding `pci-stub.ids=<pci id 2>,<pci id 2>` to my Grub boot option. The two PCI IDs I'm using now are for the same GPU, but the IDs are different.

I recently purchased a TP-Link NIC, and the [manual](http://www.tp-link.com/Resources/document/TG-3468_User_Guide.pdf) says it is using a Realtek 8xxx chipset. Apparently this is the same chipset used by my integrated NIC, as `lspci -nn` shows the same output, except the PCI bus ID is 08:00 instead of 06:00 for my integrated NIC. Given that the `pci-stub.ids` line uses the 8 hexadecimal values for the PCI ID, how do I attach only one of my NICs to the PCI stub driver?

EDIT: Here is some of the `lshw` output:

```
*-pci:5
         description: PCI bridge
         product: SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 15
         bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
         capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
            logical name: enp6s0
            version: 06
            serial: 90:2b:34:xx:xx:xx
            size: 1Gbit/s
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.1.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s

*-pci:7
         description: PCI bridge
         product: SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2)
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 15.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:15.2
         configuration: driver=pcieport
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
            logical name: enp8s0
            version: 06
            serial: c4:e9:84:xx:xx:xx
            size: 1Gbit/s
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw ip=192.168.1.142 latency=0 link=yes multicas
```

Comment: Looking at the source code for pci-stub, you should be able to use the subsystem ID (SSID) and subsystem vendor ID (SVID) to differentiate between the the two NICs.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 Thanks! I've updated my answer with some more hardware info, but I'm still not sure how I can determine what an SVID is vs. an SSID, and which of them I get running `lspci -nn`